# Calculating road condition score percentages for each zip code with SQL query in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, sql, length

I have a shapefile that holds information about the condition of a road network that runs across several cities (zip codes):

- The road network is split into segments of various lengths (meters)
- Each segment is split into 10 meters parts
- Each part has a road condition score ranging from 1 to 5 (1 being worst and 5 best)
- Each city area contains several segments of the road network (city zip code)

Using one SQL query, I would like to have for each city the percentages of each score relative to the total length of the city segments. For example :

Zip code 80100 has a total of xxx meters of which :

- aa % has a score of 5
- bb % has a score of 4
- cc % has a score of 3
- dd % has a score of 2
- ee % has a score of 1

Thanks in advance and I hope I am not confusing you :)

[image]

Comment: Here is my guess, but I know at least the percentage part (main query) is wrong. Any help would be very appreciated :

-- Parts total per city
WITH
total_length AS (
SELECT
tt.city,
count(distinct tt.part) AS total_segment_part
FROM(
SELECT DISTINCT
ZIP_CODE AS city,
SEGMENT_ID id AS id,
ROAD_TYPE AS road_type,
part AS part
FROM "Road_network"
) AS tt
WHERE tt.road_type = "county_road"
GROUP BY tt.city
),

Comment: -- Road score (1 to 5)
road_score AS (
  SELECT
    ZIP_CODE AS city,
    ROAD_TYPE AS road_type,
    ROAD_SCORE,
    count(*) as RScount
  FROM "Road_network"
  where road_type = "county_road"
  group by ROAD_SCORE, city
)
-- Main query
SELECT
  tot.city,
  tot.total_segment_part,
  typ.ROAD_SCORE,
  typ.RScount AS RS_Count,
  typ.RScount / total_segment_part * 100 AS PRCT
FROM
  total_length AS tot
  INNER JOIN road_score AS typ ON tot.city = typ.city
;

Comment: Sorry for the text formatting, I don't know how to fix it :(

Comment: Up. Nobody has an answer ?